# How to test for a condition in every action in MVC without having to write it inline?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need that every action in a controller checks for a specific condition.

If that condition is not met, the user must be redirected a specific action.

How do I do this without having to check the result of that condition in every action?

While writing this, it occourred to me that I could user an Attribute like the AuthorizeAttribute.

Do you have any thoughts on this? Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a custom class `ActionFilterAttribute` that overrides the `OnActionExecuting` method.  You can use the `Result` property for the `ActionFilterContext` to have it redirect to the appropriate View.